# Make a square width longer while keeping corners round

Tags: css, background, position, background-image

I have a background image  for example

[image]

What I want to do is make the length longer but keep the rounded corners where they are. I know there is a CSS trick out there that does this (they use it for iPhone web apps) but I can't find it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for the scale9grid?: https://code.google.com/p/scale9grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..........................***[.Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Is37fjpQ)***

Hi now it's very simple

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

used to this **css**

```
div{
width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:20px;
  border:solid 10px blue;
  box-shadow:20px 20px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:20px 20px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:20px 20px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Is37fjpQ)***

---

Same as u want this

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/3FnaH6pt)***